# Sort array of Rails of type MySQL::Result

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have an array of results which I get from SQL by using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` command. (I cannot use ActiveRecord queries like `Object.where()` because the table has no corresponding model)

I get an array as:

```
2800  1.7  1
2000  4.5  0
2107  3.0  0
2107  5.6  1
3435  2.3  0
3425  0.0  0
3425  1.3  0
1980  2.0  0
```

Now I want to sort this 2D array by the values in the 3rd column, so that all rows with a value of 1 in 3rd column move to the bottom, but want to keep all the rows with the same value in the 1st column to be together.

The resulting sorted array should look like this:

```
2000  4.5  0
3435  2.3  0
3425  0.0  0
3425  1.3  0
1980  2.0  0
2800  1.7  1
2107  3.0  0
2107  5.6  1
```

Now I know this can be done by using a sum query on the 3rd column or by using the `sort_by` method on the array, but I'm unable formulate a correct query. Any pointers on how to proceed will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you not sort them with your SQL?

Comment: that is what I want to know - How do I formulate a query so that all rows with a value of 1 in the 3rd column are moved down along with other rows with a same value in 1st column. 
(as in the example, both rows containing 2107 are moved down, since one of them has a value of 1 in the 3rd column)

Comment: Can you show the query which you are using?

Comment: Why don't you just add a (readonly) `ActiveRecord` model for that table?

Comment: @spickermann unfortunately that's not my decision to make.
@AmitBadhekaPykihStaff it's just the basic `select * from TABLE_NAME order by 3rd_COLUMN` right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via SQL:

```
( SELECT t.* FROM mytable t 
LEFT JOIN mytable tt ON t.a = tt.a AND tt.c = 1 
WHERE tt.a IS NULL) 
UNION 
( SELECT t.* FROM mytable t 
  JOIN mytable tt ON t.a = tt.a AND tt.c = 1 
  ORDER by t.c, t.a
)
```

Here I splitted the query into 2 parts: the second part searches all records with 3rd column being 1 and all their neighbours by 1st column, i.e.

```
> (select t.* from mytable t join mytable tt ON t.a = tt.a AND tt.c = 1 ORDER by t.c, t.a);
+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    |
+------+------+------+
| 2107 |    3 |    0 |
| 2107 |    6 |    1 |
| 2800 |    2 |    1 |
+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The first part just negates it, i.e. searches everything else. After that I just put them in right order via `UNION` clause.

Seems to work fine:

```
mysql> (select t.* from mytable t left join mytable tt ON t.a = tt.a AND tt.c = 1 WHERE tt.a IS NULL) UNION (select t.* from mytable t join mytable tt ON t.a = tt.a AND tt.c = 1 ORDER by t.c, t.a);
+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    |
+------+------+------+
| 2000 |    5 |    0 |
| 3435 |    2 |    0 |
| 3425 |    0 |    0 |
| 3425 |    1 |    0 |
| 1980 |    2 |    0 |
| 2800 |    2 |    1 |
| 2107 |    3 |    0 |
| 2107 |    6 |    1 |
+------+------+------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try handling it in ruby by the following code

```
array = [[2800 , 1.7,  1],[2000 , 4.5,  0],[2107 , 3.0,  0],[2107 , 5.6,  1],[3435 , 2.3,  0],[3425 , 0.0,  0],[3425 , 1.3,  0],[1980 , 2.0,  0]]

array.sort_by {|a| a[2]}
 # => [[1980, 2.0, 0], [2000, 4.5, 0], [2107, 3.0, 0], [3425, 1.3, 0], [3425, 0.0, 0], [3435, 2.3, 0], [2107, 5.6, 1], [2800, 1.7, 1]]
```

Comment: But I want to keep the rows with the same value in 1st column together. In your example, rows with values 2107 are split.

Comment: Yes, sorry i did not read the question properly. I will make an edit